# PHP - If statement always evaluating as true?

Tags: php, if-statement

So I can't get my head around this if statement.

What I am trying to do is get the person logged in from $_SESSION["user_name"] and if it matches one of two possible "admin" users, to give extra functionality. But it's always firing true.

For the example I'm going to have three users: Emma, John and Robert. Emma and John should be allowed the extra "admin functionality", but Robert is not allowed it. So...

My statement is:

```
if ($_SESSION["user_name"] === "emma" or "john"){
//give extra functionality as well as basic functionality
} else {
//give just basic functionality
```

But this is always firing true, so when I log in as my test account with the username Robert, he is also getting the extra functionality.

I've tried changing the quotation marks `"` of `$_SESSION` to apostrophes `'`, and also tried changing the operator from `===` to `==`. I even tried `=` but found the hard way that this was setting my `$_SESSION` variable to "emma".

What am I doing wrong because I just can't seem to get my head around it?

If it's worth noting, this `if` statement is contained in a parent `if` statement that uses colons `:` and `endif` rather than brackets `{}`. The parent `if` statement is purely there to decide on what functionality to output based a column returned being empty or a user's name in there.

Comment: I suggest you use `||` instead of `or`. They are not exactly the same.

Comment: use || operator and should be compared with both sides 
($_SESSION["user_name"] === "emma" || $_SESSION["user_name"]=== "john")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to redeclare the full condition:

```
if ($_SESSION["user_name"] === "emma" or $_SESSION["user_name"] === "john"){
    //give extra functionality as well as basic functionality
} else {
   ...
}
```

**Update With Explanation:**

The pseudo code syntax for if statements is:

```
if ([some condition] [and/or] [another condition]) {
    // then do some stuff
}
```

each of those [condition] statements is evaluated as either ["truthy" or "falsey"](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). So your original question could be re-written something like this:

```
if ([$_SESSION["user_name"] is equal to "emma"] or ["john" is not false, 0, or null]) {
    // we will always get in here
}
```

Since "john" will always be "truthy" (it is not false, null, 0) it will always pass the condition.

Comment: This was first, so this will be voted as the answer because I saw this answer and then whilst trying what jpschroeder suggested and finding it works, the other answers appeared. It seems so basic but I literally didn't know. So "john" was essentially "true", so the server was reading `if($_SESSION["user_name] = "emma" or true){` Thanks so much!

Comment: alternatively you may want to use `if (in_array($_SESSION['user_name'], array('emma','john')))`

Answer (score 3):

The term `"john"` as an expression is `true`:

```
if ( "john" )
```

will evaluate to true and not throwing any syntax errors.

What you want is:

```
if ($_SESSION["user_name"] === "emma" || $_SESSION["user_name"] === "john") {
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this for me, I didn't realise you had to redeclare the complete condition for each possibility. I will vote your answer +1 because jpschroeder just about pipped you with the correct answer, but I appreciate it extremely! Thank you Axel Amthor.

Answer (score 2):

It may help to break this into steps. PHP will evaluate everything to the left of or to see if it's true or false. Then it will evaluate what's on the right of the or.

Turns out, `"john"` evaluates to `true`.

You're looking for:

```
if ($_SESSION["user_name"] === "emma" or $_SESSION["user_name"] === "john") {
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
if (($_SESSION["user_name"] === "emma") || ($_SESSION["user_name"] === "john"))
{
   //do something
}
else
{
  //other thing
}
```